# How can I have two dependent Jenkins builds use the same revision of the software?

Tags: svn, build, jenkins, multiplatform

We have a release build structure which looks something like this:

> Project U (upstream):
>
> - Is a matrix project
> - Runs on multiple platforms to create released files for each platform.
> - These put the subversion revision number inside various files.
> - Archives artifacts back to Jenkins
> - Triggers build on Project D
>
> Project D (downstream):
>
> - Is not a matrix project
> - Checks out just the top-level directory and a subdirectory containing release scripts
> - Pulls artifacts from the successful build of Project U
> - Uses the subversion revision number to decide where to copy the merged results.

I don't know if this is the *right* way to structure this to work around the limitations of Jenkins, but it's the only way we were able to figure it out with the immense lack of useful documentation.

Anyway, the problem we get is that things like this happen:

- 18:00 trigger kicks off Project U
- Project U checks out SVN revision 30,000 and builds the software
- At 18:05, some guy working out of the office checks in some new code
- Project U finishes building at 18:25 and triggers Project D
- Project D checks out SVN revision 30,001 and does the uploads

The result is that we end up with files on our web server which the release process thinks is version 30,001 but which is actually 30,000.

(This isn't just for the release build, mind you. We also see it for unit tests - the build which compiles the software and the build which runs the tests can be different versions, causing tests which rely on checking the contents of the source directory to fail because some source files don't have corresponding compiled files.)

I tried to use the "Parameterized Trigger" plugin to pass the Subversion revision through, but just configuring it to pass the revision number through doesn't seem to be enough, because the triggered project isn't using the number it's being passed. I can't find any kind of setting on the second project related to this, but Jenkins' UI is such a dog's breakfast that I would be surprised if anyone can find anything in it.

Does anyone know how to do this sort of thing? *Surely* we're not the only company in the world trying to release our software on multiple platforms?

Comment: FWIW, the workaround I'm using at the moment is to use a single top-level directory in project D. So I have to pay the cost of checking out a lot of useless parts of the project, but by doing this, it avoids the bug which makes "Parameterized Trigger" not work.

Answer (score 3):

I think the [Tracking SVN Plugin](http://wiki.hudson-ci.org/display/HUDSON/Tracking+SVN+Plugin) may solve your problem.

Comment: Potentially interesting, the worry is the bit where it says "the revision tracking will happen for any URL in this project that exactly matches the tracked project."... which makes me think that it doesn't work for sub-URLs.

Answer (score 1):

You can do some thing like the following.

1. Use Parameterized Plugin and pass SVN revision to the down stream project.
2. In the down stream project, no need to select svn as the source code management tool. Instead, add a first build set up to update your working directory to the revision which is passed from upstream project.

`cd $workspace`

`svn update -r$pameter`

I have done like this for one of our projects and it is working fine.

If you are using clean build, instead of `svn update` you can use checkout also the same way.

`svn checkout url://repository/path@$parameter`

or

`svn checkout -r $parameter url://repository/path`